# Use Git repository as a Mirror in Maven?

Tags: git, maven

I have a scenario where Maven (running Maven 3) project dependencies (plugin jars etc) are hosted in a Git repository for ease of maintenance. Due to corporate policy, I am looking to setup a internal Mirror for Maven that points to the above Git repository to fetch artifacts. I cannot seem to get 'ssh' to work for the purpose of setting up mirror url in settings.xml:

```
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
    ...
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    <url>ssh://<server_name>/path/repo-name.git</url>
  </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

I read that Maven does not support ssh out of the box and I could not get additional plugin to work. Is there a better way to get this to work? Maybe the git-scm plugin?

Comment: Can you not try setting up the git repo to be readable over http(s)?

Comment: Yes, install Apache and configure it to serve up the files located in the git working directory

Comment: Best thing is to setup a repository manager and simply deploy those dependencies into the repository manager. Makes life easier.